# a foreign key constraint fails after creating database on new server

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I'm trying to insert a record but I'm getting a "a foreign key constraint fails" error. I have been searching around and seeing that every time this issue comes up, it is because the primary key of the record they are trying to add does not exist in the table that is being referenced. In this case, I see the primary key existing in the referenced table but I am still not able to insert the record.

A model with model_id of 171 exists but when trying to add a model_feature record with that id it fails:

```
mysql> select distinct model_id from model;
+----------+
| model_id |
+----------+
|      167 |
|      168 |
|      169 |
|      170 |
|      171 |
+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO model_feature (feature_position, model_id, feature_name)  VALUES (0, 171, 'my_feature');
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bpp`.`model_feature`, CONSTRAINT `model_feature_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`model_id`) REFERENCES `Model` (`model_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

Here are the details of model_feature:

```
mysql> show create table model_feature;
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table         | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| model_feature | CREATE TABLE `model_feature` (
  `model_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `feature_name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `feature_position` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `model_feature_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`model_feature_id`),
  KEY `model_id` (`model_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `model_feature_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`model_id`) REFERENCES `Model` (`model_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1343 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show columns from model_feature;
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field            | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| model_id         | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| feature_name     | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| feature_position | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| model_feature_id | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| timestamp        | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please note that I have this database on my Mac and I recently copied the schema over to AWS by way of mysqldump-ing the data, scp-ing it to my instance, loading it in and deleting the records (I imagine there's a better way of doing this but that seemed easy). It is on the AWS instance that this is failing. The same insert works fine on my Mac/OSX.

Any advice on why this is failing?

Comment: Do you have a trigger on the table?

Comment: In one place you have the table spelled ```model``` and in the other it's ```Model```. Table names are case sensitive.

Comment: @GordonLinoff no trigger

Comment: @SloanThrasher the show create table yields the same capitalizations on my local instance of the database

Comment: @zcarciu . . . (1) Case sensitivity can be based on a server setting.  (2) Could one of the tables be in a different database?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, SloanThrasher it's definitely the case sensitivity. I'll play around with the settings and might have to just reload it keeping in mind the case.

Comment: You could just use ALTER TABLE to change the foreign key definition. Just make sure the table name matches the model table spelling/capitalization.

Comment: looks like https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/1983

Comment: @SloanThrasher that worked, thanks!
mysql> alter table model_feature drop foreign key model_feature_ibfk_1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> alter table model_feature add constraint foreign key (model_id) references model (model_id) on delete cascade;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO model_feature (feature_position, model_id, feature_name)  VALUES (0, 171, 'my_feature');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)